# Existence of connection mapping

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-fields

Recently I posted a question about the horizontal/vertical decomposition of the double tangent space. In it, I invoked the below theorem. I cannot seem to find a good proof of it, specifically of the part where the vectors  $X$ and $Y$ are defined.

To be sure, I have found a seemingly good one in the below reference; however, the book is in German and my attempts to translate it have been faulty. Page 43 1975 edition:

D. Gromoll, W. Klingenberg, W. Meyer. Riemannsche geometric im groben

Theorem. Let $M$ be a differential manifold with an affine connection $\nabla$. Then, there exists a unique differentiable function $K: TTM \longrightarrow TM$, called the connection function, that satisfies the following conditions:

(1) If $v \in TM$ and $\pi(v) = p$, where $\pi: TM \longrightarrow M$ is the canonical projection, then $K(T_v TM) \subseteq T_p M$.

(2) $K_v := K|_{T_v TM}: T_v TM \longrightarrow T_p M$ is a linear map.

(3) If $v \in TM$ and $w \in T_v TM$ are such that $w = d_p X(Y)$, where $Y \in T_p M$ and $X \in {X \in \mathfrak{X}(M): X(p) = v}$, then $K(w) = \nabla_Y X$.

Comment: Your third condition already tells you how to define $K$. So, just check that if you define $K$ that way it satisfies (1) and (2), and that it is unique (well, this is clear because you have a formula depending only on $\nabla$).

Comment: The third condition tells us how to define $K$ subject to $Y$ and $X$ existing, but we need to prove they exist. Also, they may not be unique, in which case we need to show that $K$ does not vary according to $K$. The German paper shows this in half a page, I think they write what such $X$ would look like if written in coordinates, and then equate it with the $v$ written in coordinates. I know they use coordinates but not sure how. I’m not too sure how they handle defining $Y$ at all

Comment: there are standard theorems like $(\nabla_YX)(p)$ depends only on $Y(p)$, because $\nabla_YX$ is $C^{\infty}(M)$-linear in the $Y$ slot. Alternatively, you can look at the coordinate definition of $(\nabla_YX)(p)$; you’ll see that only the $Y^i(p)$ appear, no derivatives of $Y^i$. Also, for any vector $v\in T_pM$, there exists a vector field $X$ on $M$ such that $X(p)=v$ (take a chart around $p$, and define $X$ to be constantly $v$ in this chart. then use a bump function around $p$ to extend $X$ to all of $M$) etc.

Comment: I believe that’s not so simple in terms of the bump function as there’s the condition with regard to $w(=d_pX(Y))$ that they should satisfy too. However, your comments do help, especially the observations abour the non-dependency on the derivatives of $Y$.

Comment: in the chart, you can define things such that $X(p)=v$ and its derivative in the direction $Y(p)$ is $w$ (roughly speaking, you’re merely specifying the value of $X$ and its first derivative at only one point, so this is a very doable condition). The purpose of the bump function is simply to make the domain of $X$ all of $M$, not just some open subset.

Answer (score 1):

Let $E$ be a vector bundle over $M$ and denote the natural projection map by
\begin{align*}
  \pi_E: E &\rightarrow M.
\end{align*}
Given $p \in M$ and $e \in E_p$, observe that the pushforward map of $\pi_E$ defines a linear map
$$
  (\pi_E)_*: T_eE \rightarrow T_pM
$$

Given an affine connection $\nabla$ on $E$, we want to show that there is a natural bundle map
$$
  K: TE \rightarrow E
$$
such that if $s$ is a section of $E$ on a neighborhood of $p\in E$ and $X\in T_pM$, then
$$ \nabla_Xs(p) = K(s_*(X)).$$
Given any $p \in M$, $e \in E_p$ and $\dot{e} \in T_eE$, there is a curve $s: I \rightarrow E$ such that $s(0) = e$ and $s'(0) =\dot{e}$. Then $s$ is a section of $E$ along the curve $c = \pi_E\circ s: I \rightarrow M$. Taking the covariant derivative of $s$, let
$$
  K_e(\dot{e}) = \nabla_Xs(0) \in E_p,
$$
where $X=(\pi_E)_*(s’(0))$. If you write this all out with respect to a frame of sections of $E$, you can confirm this is a bundle map.